# How can I create custom android virtual device, using my own images?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I create custom android virtual device, using my own images? I've been trying to change default *.img-s on my own in sdk\platforms\android\images but it didn't help - the emulator didn't launch or frozen.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: did my answer below help you?

Comment: you should click the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your .img files already, you use the AVD manager (available in ADT) to create the new AVD, then you copy the system.img in to your AVD directory. C:\Users\Ryan\.android\avd\mycustomavd\

here is a video that shows the steps: http://www.android-theme.com/taxonomy/term/36. There is no audio.

Comment: as @oneat wrote, the link is not working. Any other pointers?

Comment: Downvoted because providing links to external resources without describing how it's actually done leads to a situation like this where the provided answer is not helpful if the resource becomes unavailable.

Comment: @JulianSievers, Ryan already provided you with the steps to do it and additionally provided the link for more descriptive instructions, if needed.